# How to parse this xml in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I want to parse an xml file into a dictionary the Dictionary  looks like this

```
"250", 0.110050251256281
"150", 0.810050256425628
"850", 0.701005025125628
"550", 0.910050251256281
```

How can i parse the data above into a dictionary from the xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<calibration>
  <zoom level="250">0,110050251256281</zoom>
  <zoom level="150">0,810050256425628</zoom>
  <zoom level="850">0,701005025125628</zoom>
  <zoom level="550">0,910050251256281</zoom>
</calibration>
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Use a StringReader and Split to break up the CSV file and then use an XDocument to create the XML. Plenty of information on MSDN.

Comment: What code do you have already? If you show it, we can try to fix it.

Comment: The question is... [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("your file");
var nodes = doc.Element("calibration").Elements("zoom");
Dictionary<string, double> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();

foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XElement item in nodes)
{
    var level = item.Attribute("level").Value;
    var val = double.Parse(item.Value);
    myDictionary.Add(level, var);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
  var xml = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <calibration>
                  <zoom level="250">0,110050251256281</zoom>
                  <zoom level="150">0,810050256425628</zoom>
                  <zoom level="850">0,701005025125628</zoom>
                  <zoom level="550">0,910050251256281</zoom>
              </calibration>"

  var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  var zooms = doc.Descendants("zoom")
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("level").Value, x => x.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below... it will help you...

**Code :**

```
 System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "//XML//Sample.xml");
 System.Xml.XmlNodeList CNodes = doc.SelectNodes("/calibration/zoom");
 Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in CNodes)
   dictionary.Add(Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["level"].Value), node.InnerText);
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: op has asked for `linq-xml` solution..This doesn't ans his question!..also linq-xml is better then that **old** low-level api

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XmlFile");
var elements = (from items in doc.Elements("calibration").Elements("zoom")
                select items).ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("level").Value, x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Don't forget to add some errorhandling and you may want to load the xml from a file instead of a hardcoded string.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<calibration>
<zoom level=""250"">0,110050251256281</zoom>
<zoom level=""150"">0,810050256425628</zoom>
<zoom level=""850"">0,701005025125628</zoom>
<zoom level=""550"">0,910050251256281</zoom>
</calibration>";

System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("calibration/zoom");
var dicNodes = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    dicNodes.Add(node.Attributes["level"].Value, node.InnerText);
}
```